# Laravel, saving related before saving master record

Tags: laravel, submit, dropzone

I have a form in my laravel app where a user can create a 'document', to this 'document' I can relate more other info with relationships such us 'files' that has a relationship with the 'document' table to the 'files' table.
I use dropzonejs to upload file via Ajax so I need to save files before to submit the form, so before to saving the document.
The problem is that the file has a column 'document_id' related with the 'documents' table. How can I save it?

Thanks :)

Comment: With other uploaders I've used, the default behaviour has been to upload the file automatically as soon as it's selected, but this automatic upload could be turned off, and then triggered manually once you've got the additional data you need. Can you do that with dropzonejs? I checked their docs: autoProcessQueue: false, then call processQueue when you're ready.

Comment: It could be useful but I don't sent form via Ajax, so I can't call 'processQueue' after I save my form data...

Comment: Use DB::transaction

Comment: I was also thinking something like this. But when I have to start it? I save “document” on first file upload? Or is not necessary to save the document first?

Comment: Why would be problem to save document and after that save file instance? Also without providing code used there it is hard to tell more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guess the document_id before creating a record in the documents table. So you can upload files and manage an array/hidden-field with file details and submit all in one go.

Comment: If I would use your suggestions, how do you suggest to save them if I had multiple files to save in my hidden element?

Comment: Use different table for files